# Powershell OnlyInJobError

Tags: powershell, permissions, jobs

Weird problem I saw today and I don't understand.
Is there a difference beetween running a script manually in the ISE or Pshell, and as a job?
If I run it manually the code doesn't throw an error - runs smoothly:

```
Get-ChildItem "\\SERVER\S$\ROOT\DIR" -Recurse | Where {$_.creationtime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-35)} | Remove-Item -Force -Include *.conf
```

But if I run it via Job and let the it export the $error to a txtfile this happens:
Are the rights of my running machine different to the rights of the scheduled job?

```
Get-ChildItem : Zugriff verweigert
In Zeile:81 Zeichen:1
+ Get-ChildItem "\\SERVER\S$\ROOT\DIR" -Recurse | Where 
{$_.creati ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedA 
   ccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.Pow 
   erShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Zugriff verweigert = Access denied

Oh, totally forgot to tell about my windows rights.
Normally the Server I am connecting to is blocked for everybody - except for login with credentials ofc. But somehow my manual powershell script is able to delete and create files?
In "job-mode" it loses it's abilities.

Edit:
Same for the Test-Path commandlet. Manually it shows me true or false. Via job it throws an error.

EDIT - SAME PROBLEM COMPLETELY DIFFERENT Commandlets:

```
$username = "Administrator"
$password = cat C:\securestring.txt | convertto-securestring
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $password

New-PSDrive -Name Z -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\Server\ROOT -Credential $cred -Persist

test-path 'Z:'

Remove-PSDrive -Name Z -PSProvider FileSystem
```

This works!

This does not:

```
$jobname        = "Test5"
$JobTrigger     = New-JobTrigger -Daily -At "00:18 PM"
$MyOptions      = New-ScheduledJobOption -ContinueIfGoingOnBattery -HideInTaskScheduler -RunElevated
 Register-ScheduledJob -name "$jobname" -scriptblock  {


$username = "Administrator"
$password = cat C:\securestring.txt | convertto-securestring
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $password

New-PSDrive -Name Z -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\Server\ROOT -Credential $cred -Persist

test-path 'Z:'

Remove-PSDrive -Name Z -PSProvider FileSystem

} -trigger $JobTrigger –ScheduledJobOption $MyOptions
```

Comment: " if I run it via Job" ? how ? start-job, using a task scheduler, something else ?

Comment: @Kayasax Register-ScheduledJob -name "test" -scriptblock {$SCRIPT} -trigger $JobTrigger –ScheduledJobOption $MyOptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is not exactly an answere to my original question, but I was able to work around my problem by using the invoke-command and test-path from there and giving argument via the -arg.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $FTPADRESS -ArgumentList $DIRECTORY -ScriptBlock {param ($DIR)
                    $check = Test-Path -Path "\\SERVER\ROOT\$DIR"
                    if ($check -ne $true) {New-Item -ItemType directory -Path "\\SERVER\ROOT\$DIR"}
                                                                              }
```

Same works with the get-childitem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the job running under the SYSTEM account. Use the **-Credential** parameter to provide your account credentials (whatever account you're logged in with when you successfully run the command interactively).

BTW, **Register-ScheduledJob** uses the Task Scheduler. You can check the properties of the job in Task Scheduler to see what account it's configured to run as.

Comment: That's what makes it so weird for me. I am not even logged in as an Administrator. And normally I should not be able to test the path to the Server. But as long as I keep doing everything manually it works. Credentials didn't change anything - even with the Domainadmin Credentials - because this one Server is not a member of our domain. ~~ Checked the Task Scheduler. Saw nothing special there.... Properties are all how I defined them.

Comment: But what account is it running under? You should see that on the General tab of the task's Properties.

Comment: There is written my personal account. But I tried it as Administrator - same problem

Comment: I edited my question, maybe this makes everything more clearly